# How do i solve the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' " on specifying the k-clustering value?

Tags: python, k-means

I'm trying to find the best values  of k clustering, but it is showing error

```
k_range = range(1,10)
sse = []
max_iter = 300
init = 'k-means++'
n_init = 10
for k in k_range:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter =  max_iter, init = init, n_init = n_init)
    km.fit(df[['Age','Income($)']])
    sse.append(km.inertia_)
```

Comment: There's no call to `split()` in the code you posted. Please post the full traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add a tag for the library that KMeans comes from.

Comment: here is the traceback :AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-8d6c17326a88> in <module>
      6 for k in k_range:
      7     km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter =  max_iter, init = init, n_init = n_init)
----> 8     km.fit(df[['Age','Income($)']])
      9     sse.append(km.inertia_)

Answer (score 8):

Instead of downgrading `numpy`, you can try this:

```bash
pip install -U threadpoolctl
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

seems like an issue caused  by a numpy.
importing a specific version of numpy ( downgrading it to 1.21.4) should fix the problem

```
import numpy 
numpy.__version__ 
'1.21.4'
```

make sure, you not importing numpy as np again afterwards before you assign your clastering model

Answer (score -1):

Setting the minimum value in your range to a value greater than 1 will fix this problem
EX: range(2,10)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).